# Is there a way to interrupt login with an option menu

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to interrupt login with a option menu asking for role in a system with multiple roles for user.

For example, User can login under company profile or individual profile, so we would want to filter based on the role the user select. The system have one user with multiple roles.